# root directory empty no folders on digitalocean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, digital-ocean

when i connect remotely to digital ocean server by doing ssh deploy@dropletIP i type pwd this comes out

```
/home/deploy
```

when i type "ls" nothing show up
when I do cd shared it says

```
 -bash: cd: shared: No such file or directory
```

when i type .. or cd - or /

```
No command 'cd-' found, did you mean:
..: command not found
-bash: /: Is a directory
```

Im trying to navigate to shared/config so i can create database.yml and secrets.yml

Comment: You can't navigate to a folder that doesn't exist. Why did you think something should be there? normally your capistrano deployment script would take care of everything for you

Comment: I was following the instruction in this link https://medium.com/@adamjgordon24/how-to-let-the-world-see-your-sweet-sweet-ruby-on-rails-json-api-using-ubuntu-14-06-and-nginx-ebe0a5dddbed @jamesc

Comment: Nothing shows up when you type ls because there is nothing there. That's not really telling me anything at all. You have an empty server.You have not described what should be there after what steps you have taken. If you want a folder to change into then `mkdir some_folder` will do that for you however your capistrano deployment script will setup your rails env when you cap deploy and will grab your code from your git source code repository, bitbucket maybe? and place your code where it should be. i.e.the applications folder will automatically be created along with the full application code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cause you logged in to ur remote server as SFTP, that will make u go to different directory than logging in as SSH